# How to make my kubernetes to take my latest docker image?

Tags: kubernetes

Problem

A frequent question that comes up on Slack and Stack Overflow is how to trigger an update to a Deployment/RS/RC when the image tag hasn't changed but the underlying image has.

Consider:

1. There is an existing Deployment with image foo: latest
2. The user builds a new image foo: latest
3. The user pushes foo: latest to their registry
4. The user wants to do something here to tell the Deployment to pull the new image and do a rolling-update of existing pods

For Example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: worker-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: worker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: worker
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: worker
          image: stephengrider/multi-worker
          env:
            - name: REDIS_HOST
              value: redis-cluster-ip-service
            - name: REDIS_PORT
              value: "6379"
```

And now I have made changes in my multiWorker image

and redeploys the deployment, but it doesn't fetch the latest image?

Comment: The standard answer is to not use a `:latest` tag; use a unique tag per build, and then when you update your deployment spec, Kubernetes will do a rolling update for you.  As a bonus, "yesterday's build tag" is well-defined in a way "latest as of an hour ago" isn't, so it's easy to roll back a failed build.

Answer (score 3):

The **default pull policy is `IfNotPresent` which causes the Kubelet to skip pulling an image if it already exists**. [Refer Link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images)

If you would like to always force a pull, you can do one of the following:

1: **set** the `imagePullPolicy` of the container to `Always`.

2: **omit** the `imagePullPolicy` and use `:latest` as the tag for the image to use.

3: **omit** the `imagePullPolicy` and the tag for the image to use.

4: **enable** the `AlwaysPullImages` admission controller.

> Note that you should **avoid using :latest tag**, we should avoid using the :latest tag when deploying containers in production as it is harder to track which version of the image is running and more difficult to roll back properly.

Various `imagePullPolicy` and the `tag` of the image affect when the kubelet attempts to pull the specified image listed below. [Refer Link for Details](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images)

1) imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent: the image is pulled only if it is not already present locally.

2) imagePullPolicy: Always: the image is pulled every time the pod is started.

3) imagePullPolicy is omitted and either the image tag is :latest or it is omitted: Always is applied.

4) imagePullPolicy is omitted and the image tag is present but not :latest: IfNotPresent is applied.

5) imagePullPolicy: Never: the image is assumed to exist locally. No attempt is made to pull the image.